# Overlapping UITextView when add text to UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I created `UIViewController` in `Storyboard` and added `tableview` as a `Subview`. Its working fine. In that `tableview` I added cells programatically and each cell contains `UITextFields` or `UITextView`. `UITextFields` are working fine. But `UITextViews` have some troubles. EX: When I add text to `UITextView` then bellow `UITextViews` are overlapped. why is that ? I tried to sort out whole day. But still I couldn't. :(

```
    case cellResponseNote:
        cell = [tableView.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierResponseNote];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierResponseNote];
             cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cellNotesHeight);
            //cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cellNotesHeight);
            if (!self.txtVwResponseNote) {
              // self.txtVwResponseNote = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
                self.txtVwResponseNote = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cellNotesHeight)];
                [self.txtVwResponseNote setScrollEnabled:NO];
                [self.txtVwResponseNote setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
                [self.txtVwResponseNote setDelegate:self];

                [self.txtVwResponseNote setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
                [self.txtVwResponseNote setInputAccessoryView:self.keyboardToolbar];
                [self setupMailData:indexPath.row];
            }
        }
        self.txtVwResponseNote.editable = !(self.isMailForReview);
       // [cell.contentView addSubview:self.txtVwResponseNote];
        [cell addSubview:self.txtVwResponseNote];
        contentSubview = self.txtVwResponseNote;
```

[image]

In this image bottom You can see three cells. ( bellow Footer)  When I add text value for top text view. Then overlap the next text view.
Bellow image you can see only two textviews. Bottom text view is not showing.

[image]

So what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all as an answer try setting the height of the cell by following method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   case cellResponseNote:
        return cellNotesHeight;
   default:
        return defaultHeight;
}
```

Also I recommend you not to share the textview property. Instead try modifying your code like this and see whether your code works.

```
case cellResponseNote:
    cell = [tableView.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierResponseNote];
    UITextView *txtVwResponseNote = nil;
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierResponseNote];
         cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cellNotesHeight);
        //cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cellNotesHeight);
        //if (!self.txtVwResponseNote) {
          // self.txtVwResponseNote = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
            txtVwResponseNote = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cellNotesHeight)];
            [txtVwResponseNote setScrollEnabled:NO];
            [txtVwResponseNote setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
            [txtVwResponseNote setDelegate:self];

            [txtVwResponseNote setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            [txtVwResponseNote setInputAccessoryView:self.keyboardToolbar];
            [txtVwResponseNote setTag:100];
        //}
    } else {
        txtVwResponseNote = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:100]
    }

    [self setupMailData:indexPath.row];
    txtVwResponseNote.editable = !(self.isMailForReview);
   // [cell.contentView addSubview:txtVwResponseNote];
    [cell addSubview:self.txtVwResponseNote];
    contentSubview = self.txtVwResponseNote;
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets repeated because you added it to the cell as a subview, and then reuse the cell. Add it as a accessoryView of the cell instead, and set it to nil for the cell's that dont need it.

```
cell.accessoryView = self.txtVwResponseNote;
```

And in all other cells, set accessoryView to nil.

```
cell.accessoryView = nil;
```